# I can't disable with setEnabled(false), the button is not disabled in correct phase

Tags: selenium, jframe, webdriver

I have Selenium WebDriver `callSe.test();` + JFrame.
Here is the constructor of frame:

```
public AutoFrame() {
    textFieldVersion.setColumns(10);
    textFieldUrl.setColumns(10);
    textPaneIsBuildCorrect.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("menu"));
    btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            btnRun.setEnabled(false);
            getEnteredVer();
            CheckBuildVersion callSe = new CheckBuildVersion();
            callSe.test();
            textPaneIsBuildCorrect.setText(callSe.getIsBuildCorrect());
            if (textPaneIsBuildCorrect.getText().contains("The Build is correct!")) {
                textPaneIsBuildCorrect.setForeground(Color.blue);
            }
            else {
                textPaneIsBuildCorrect.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
            textPaneCurrentBuild.setText(callSe.getBuild());
        }
    });
    initGUI();
}
```

So I expect after `btnRun.setEnabled(false);` the button to be disabled, but is not. It's only marked and the Frame just kind of freeze. 
The button becomes non clickable (false, disabled) only when whole constructor finish. 
Why is happen like that? I want, when I press the button to be disabled, then I will put to be enable. Maybe I have to use modal dialog with PleaseWait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the Selenium Task in a separate Thread.

```
   Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //your selenium actions
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

For your case

```
 btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        btnRun.setEnabled(false);
        getEnteredVer();
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                  CheckBuildVersion callSe = new CheckBuildVersion();
            callSe.test();
            textPaneIsBuildCorrect.setText(callSe.getIsBuildCorrect());
            if (textPaneIsBuildCorrect.getText().contains("The Build is correct!")) {
                textPaneIsBuildCorrect.setForeground(Color.blue);
            }
            else {
                textPaneIsBuildCorrect.setForeground(Color.red);
            }
            textPaneCurrentBuild.setText(callSe.getBuild());
            }
        };
    thread.start();

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you! This works :) But I have now new problem, after the process  finish, the frame is not editable. Also, when I set in Class `CheckBuildVersion` with this: `textPaneCurrentBuild.setText("Test");`
The text doesn't sets in this field. Also `textPaneCurrentBuild.setText(callSe.getBuild());`
doesn't works when I'm using Threads.

Comment: debug it by puting a breakpoint on those lines and see if it going there.Also try to set the values before and after thread call